# Launching a Cordova app by redirecting to a custom URL scheme forbidden

Tags: android, cordova, content-security-policy

I'm trying to get an Android app built with Cordova to launch when a webpage that has been opened in the device's regular browser redirects the device to `myscheme://somelocation`. To this end I've added the [Custom-URL-scheme plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme) using Ionic CLI's plugin command:

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-customurlscheme --variable URL_SCHEME=myscheme
```

I've checked that my `AndroidManifest.xml` has the proper intent filter in the first `manifest/application/activity` node:

```
<intent-filter>
    <data android:scheme="myscheme" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
```

I've also allowed this scheme in the `config.xml` file

```
<allow-intent href="myscheme:" />
```

I'm testing this by navigating to a webpage, using the devices default browser, that redirects the device to `myscheme://somelocation`. The browser gives me the error `ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME`, but inspecting the console of that browser window shows the error (translated, I don't know the actual English error message) `Target has been blocked: myscheme://somelocation`.

So in a word, it doesn't work. Is this a CSP issue or has the scheme not been registered? What else do I need to do to get my app to launch?

Comment: Did you found a solution?

Comment: @kabaehr Unfortunately no, but Ionic 2 seems to have a plugin for this: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/ionic-deeplinks/ - Might be worth checking out. Even if you don't use Ionic 2, maybe you can find the solution looking through their code.